# Rectangle intersections with Java AWT

Tags: java, awt, java-2d

I have two rectangles, and I want to figure out which side they are intersecting on. I can use `Rectangle.intersects(Rectangle)` but it only tells me that the rectangles are intersecting. What I am trying to do is check whether the rectangle is intersecting on the x or y axis, but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Do  you know how to tell where one point on a graph is relative to another?  E.g. by comparing x1 to x2 and y1 to y2.  You can do the same with rectangles.  Of course if they completely overlap, you won't know which side one entered on (assuming they moved towards one another).

Comment: @WJS This is my first time using stack overflow, I'm not really sure how to respond to answers. Do you mean like distance formula, and check if the distance from the corners is 0 or less, and return an enum value for which corner it is?

Answer (score 2):

I am suggesting just using some basic math to determine where the rectangles are intersecting.

A rectangle has a location (upper left corner) and a width and a height.

- Say `R1` is at `(10,20)` and `R2` is at `(40,50)`.  Since `R1` is to the left and above `R2`, then that means that if `R2` is intersecting `R1`, `R2` must be intersecting on the right and/or below `R1`.
- But if `R2` is not as wide as `R1`, it may be intersecting only on the bottom of `R1`.
- Or if `R2` is not as high as `R1`, it may be intersecting only on the right of `R1`.
- There is also the possibility that `R1` and `R2` are completely overlapping each other.

So you will need to use the combination of the rectangles' locations and their sizes to determine exactly where the rectangles are intersecting.

The best thing to do is try and work this out on paper.  Then write your code and if you have any problems, post it and someone will assist.  When posting your answer, just edit your original post with the changes.